# mac terminal rename batch

Tags: terminal, rename

I have found how to rename from the Terminal using the `rename` command.
However, I couldn't find how to rename from a particular value? Let's say I want to rename from `title223` onwards (not necessarily from `title001`).

What would be the syntax for this?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you taking about `rename` Perl command?

Comment: It is from HomeBrew.

Comment: Okay please see the file where is at. For example run: `which rename` and if it said `/usr/bin/rename/` go there and open the file. if it was **Perl** script; then tell it here. Or more easily run: `man rename` and see what is going on.

Comment: That still does not address my question. I wonder how to rename from a specific counter k=4:10. This syntax renames from 1 onwards always:  rename 's/.+/our $i; sprintf("name_of_file%02d.jpg", 1+$i++)/e' *

Comment: okay. use `-E` or `-e` of `rename` command if you want to use any Perl code. I think you have use `my` keyword` like: `rename -E 'my $n=4 ...'`. But still your question is Not Clear Enough

Answer (score 0):

I hope I figured out your problem.

If you want to rename multiple files with this command and also what to use some **Perl** function, code, etc; you have declare it explicitly. Thus this command it not correct:

```
~ ❱ rename -n -v 's/_/printf("%.2d",$n++)/e' *.txt
Global symbol "$n" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $n"?) at (user-supplied code).
```

but this one is correct:

```
~ ❱ rename -n -v 'my $n;s/_/printf("%.2d",$n++)/e' *.txt
00rename(0_file.txt, 01file.txt)
00rename(1_file.txt, 11file.txt)
00rename(2_file.txt, 21file.txt)
00rename(3_file.txt, 31file.txt)
00rename(4_file.txt, 41file.txt)
```

but the problem with this code is that the `printf` function does not puts its result in the substitution and for fixing this we can use `sprintf`.

*putting zero-leading and `_` at the beginning*

```
~ ❱ rename -v -n 'my $n;s/^/sprintf("%.3d_",$n++)/ge' *.txt
rename(0_file.txt, 000_0_file.txt)
rename(1_file.txt, 000_1_file.txt)
rename(2_file.txt, 000_2_file.txt)
rename(3_file.txt, 000_3_file.txt)
rename(4_file.txt, 000_4_file.txt)
```

As you see all the `000_` are zero, because the `$n` is local and it is declared per line.

Thus we can make global by: `our` keyword like this:

```
~ ❱ rename -v -n 'our $n; s/^/sprintf("%.3d_",$n++)/ge' *.txt
rename(0_file.txt, 000_0_file.txt)
rename(1_file.txt, 001_1_file.txt)
rename(2_file.txt, 002_2_file.txt)
rename(3_file.txt, 003_3_file.txt)
rename(4_file.txt, 004_4_file.txt)
```

And eventually your demand: *I want to rename from title223*

I am **NOT** sure but I think you cannot use `rename` command in this way, It should work but ...!!!

And in such a case I prefer to use **Perl one-liner**

---

### Renaming with Perl non-recursive version:

```
~ ❱ perl -le '($old=$_) && s/^/sprintf("%.3d_",$n++)/e && print "$old => $_" for <*.txt>'
0_file.txt => 000_0_file.txt
1_file.txt => 001_1_file.txt
2_file.txt => 002_2_file.txt
3_file.txt => 003_3_file.txt
4_file.txt => 004_4_file.txt
```

And for beginning form a special value like `223`:

```
~ ❱ perl -le '$n=223; ($old=$_) && s/^/sprintf("%.3d_",$n++)/e && print "$old => $_" for <*.txt>'
0_file.txt => 223_0_file.txt
1_file.txt => 224_1_file.txt
2_file.txt => 225_2_file.txt
3_file.txt => 226_3_file.txt
4_file.txt => 227_4_file.txt
```

Just instead of `print "$old => $_`  use `rename $old,$_` function.

---

### Renaming with Perl recursive version:

For this one you have to use `find` command

```
~ ❱ find . -name '*.txt'
./4_file.txt
./2_file.txt
./0_file.txt
./3_file.txt
./1_file.txt
~ ❱ find . -name '*.txt' > find.log
~ ❱ 
~ ❱ # run perl with print just for test
~ ❱ 
~ ❱ perl -lne '$n=223; ($old=$_) && s/(?<=\.\/)(?=)/sprintf("%.3d_",$n++)/e && print "$old => $_"' find.log 
./4_file.txt => ./223_4_file.txt
./2_file.txt => ./223_2_file.txt
./0_file.txt => ./223_0_file.txt
./3_file.txt => ./223_3_file.txt
./1_file.txt => ./223_1_file.txt
~ ❱ 
~ ❱ # Ohhhhh Nooooo it is still 233!
~ ❱ 
~ ❱ # first solution: using BEGIN{ $n=233 }
~ ❱ 
~ ❱ perl -lne 'BEGIN{$n=223}; ($old=$_) && s/(?<=\.\/)(?=)/sprintf("%.3d_",$n++)/e && print "$old => $_"' find.log 
./4_file.txt => ./223_4_file.txt
./2_file.txt => ./224_2_file.txt
./0_file.txt => ./225_0_file.txt
./3_file.txt => ./226_3_file.txt
./1_file.txt => ./227_1_file.txt
~ ❱ 
~ ❱ # second solution is: using static declaration
~ ❱ # in Perl it is: state 
~ ❱ # thus we should use: state $n=223;
~ ❱ # but we have to turn on Perl 5 feature with -E
~ ❱ 
~ ❱ perl -lnE 'state $n=233; ($old=$_) && s/(?<=\.\/)(?=)/sprintf("%.3d_",$n++)/e && print "$old => $_"' find.log 
./4_file.txt => ./233_4_file.txt
./2_file.txt => ./234_2_file.txt
./0_file.txt => ./235_0_file.txt
./3_file.txt => ./236_3_file.txt
./1_file.txt => ./237_1_file.txt
~ ❱ 
~ ❱ # test it with rename $old,$_
~ ❱ perl -lnE 'state $n=233; ($old=$_) && s/(?<=\.\/)(?=)/sprintf("%.3d_",$n++)/e && rename $old,$_' find.log
~ ❱ 
~ ❱ # see the result:
~ ❱ 
~ ❱ ls *.txt | cat -n
     1  233_4_file.txt
     2  234_2_file.txt
     3  235_0_file.txt
     4  236_3_file.txt
     5  237_1_file.txt
```

---

**NOTE** `BEGIN{}` and `state` does not work on `rename` command. Why? I do not know :)